# Как сделать один заголовочный файл библиотеки из множества?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, библиотеки, header, lib

У меня есть библиотека. В ней множество *header*-файлов. Когда я компилирую её в `.lib`, мне нужно подключить в проекте, который использует эту `.lib`, главный *header*-файл. Этот файл подключает сотню других *header*-файлов из папок с исходными кодами библиотеки. И получается что мне нужно носить с собой все *header*-файлы, а значит и всю библиотеку в исходном виде.

Я хочу: запихать все *header*-файлы в один и носить его с собой, а не носить с собой все исходные коды библиотеки.

Как мне это сделать? И делается ли это как то стандартными средствами *Visual Studio*?

Comment: Здесь обычно стараются плохого не советовать :)

Comment: @PinkTux а что это сильно плохо? :D

Comment: Плохо это тем, что вы можете нарушить зависимости и получить потенциальные проблемы при обновлении библиотеки. Но если библиотека ваша - действительно, имеет смысл разделить изначально на две сущности: одна нужна для пользователя готовой библиотеки, вторая для её сборки (типа `lib.h` и `lib-dev.h`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имеет смысл сделать такой заголовочный файл `lib.h`, чтобы в нём было только то, что нужно для использования **готовой** библиотеки и не было ничего лишнего.

Например, Ваша библиотека использует внутри себя сущность `A`, для которой есть файл `A.h`. Если факт этой зависимости не должен быть доступен пользователю библиотеки (т.е. никакие типы из `A` не используются напрямую пользователем Вашей библиотеки), то и строка типа `#include "A.h"` не должна присутствовать в `lib.h`. А следовательно и сам файл `A.h` не нужен при распространении Вашей библиотеки.

Comment: Так я и хочу так сделать для использования **готовой** библиотеки, но я не знаю как. Возможно есть инструменты в самой Visual Studio? Ибо все эти сотни файлов переносить в один вручную...лучше уж всё как есть оставить.

Comment: @JaminPeru а на основании какой информации этот гипотетический инструмент может узнать, что оставить в `lib.h`, а что перенести внутрь?

Comment: я хочу все хедеры библиотеки запихать в один файл :).

Comment: @JaminPeru не могу Вас остановить в этом желании.

Comment: :D ладно, я понял что это не самая лучшая идея.